# Seleccionar Bases de Datos + Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

estoy haciendo una página que trabaja con 2 gestores de base de datos postgresql y sql server, postgres esta en el servidor de la aplicación y sql server puede estar en la el mismo servidor o en otro servidor  mi duda es como puedo conectar con el servidor sql server estando en otro lado y listar las base de datos que tiene para seleccionar a cual se va a conectar, debido que las base de datos no siempre tienen el mismo nombre, dejo el codigo html de lo que mas menos quiero hacer

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Conección</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Conectar Base de Datos</h2>
  <form >
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usuario">Usuario:</label>
      <input type="usuario" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" name="usuario">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd" class="mr-sm-2">Contraseña:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="pwd" placeholder="Contraseña" name="pswd">
      <label for="servidor" class="mr-sm-2">Servidor:</label>
     <input type="servidor" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="servidor" name="servidor" placeholder="Servidor">
      <label for="database" class="mr-sm-2">Base de Datos:</label>
      <select>
     <option value="">Seleccionar ...</option>     
   </select> 
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Conectar</button>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: si la base de datos no siempre sera la misma no debes crear una conexion con una base de datos especifica debes hacer una peticion al server y listar en un select o algo el listado de las base de datos y mostrar  y alli conectar con esa bd especifica

Comment: @Tegito123 como seria porque eso es lo que no se hacer, como sería el metodo o la clase

Comment: Primero que nada tu template tienes que definir todas las credenciales necesarias para conectarte a tu servidor.. es decir usuario..clave...puertos..lo que sea... una vez que el usuario ingresa eso lo recibes en tu views.py.. y mediante raw sql haces una consulta a sql server o lo que sea para saber el listado de las base de datos existentes y se las muestras al usuario..

Comment: esta es una sentencia que mandarias a tu servidor sql server para obtener la lista de base de datos: SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases

Comment: si pero antes de hacer la consulta para listar las base de datos tendria que poner usuario y contraseña y el servidor que seria una direccion ip mayormente o el localhost

Comment: si x eso te digo eso le pides al usuario que ingrese en el template es decir en tu formulario html que tienes...

Comment: si . mi template es el que puse de ejemplo cuando obtengo los datos en la vista para conectar tengo que hacer esto DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'NAME': 'my_database',
        'USER': 'my_db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_db_password',
        'HOST': 'dbserver\\ss2008',
    }
}
 pero como lo hago porque primero cuando ponga el usuario , contraseña y servidor hago un onchange para que me liste las base de datos y tengo que tener en cuenta que trabajo con 2 gestores postgesql y sqlserver

Comment: esto te va a guiar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585373/django-multiple-and-dynamic-databases

Comment: disculpa, pero soy nuevo con el trabajo con varios gestores de BD y estoy entrando en el mundo de django que me ha encantado

Comment: si es algo para guiarme lo unico que yo no tengo que crear las base de datos porque es una base de datos existente que le hice un inspectdb y deje los models que me hacen falta para obtener la información y cada cliente que tiene una BD diferente

Comment: exacto .. si... intenta.. y suerte !!

Comment: como pongo que me solucionaste la pregunta

Comment: - Primero que nada debes establecer tu template. - una vez con estos datos. en views.py recibes y creas la conexion a tu servidor. - con esta conexion extrar un listado de base de datos. - Esta lista la muestras al usuario en un select o como tu deseas.. y lsto:
referencia:
[MultiDataBase Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585373/django-multiple-and-dynamic-databases)