# Multiples Base de Datos django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7

Hola soy nuevo con django, estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde utilizo sql server 2008 el mismo, pero tengo un problema que donde voy a poner la aplicación no siempre estará conectado al mismo servidor de base de datos ni a la misma base de datos ya que tienen la misma estructura pero no el mismo nombre, mi duda es como puedo obtener mediante django el nombre de las base de datos estando en el localhost o dando un ip, saludos y espero que alguien me pueda ayudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se sabe que cuando se esta haciendo un desarrollo en donde hay una base de datos involucrada es necesario mantener un archivo donde se almacenen las credenciales de la base de datos, que posteriormente en producción estos datos cambias, es por esto que podrías tener dentro de su proyecto un archivo que se llame database.py con la siguiente estructura

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'NAME': 'my_database',
        'USER': 'my_db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_db_password',
        'HOST': 'dbserver\\ss2008',
    }
}
```

Ya en su código importa este archivo y llama estas constantes para realizar la conexión

```
import database

dbHost     = database.DATABASES['default']['HOST']
dbUsername = database.DATABASES['default']['USER']
dbPassword = database.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD']
dbName     = database.DATABASES['default']['NAME']
```

Si estas utilizando algún gestor de control de versiones como git, puedes llamar a este archivo database.sample.py para que lo tenga disponible, hacer una copia en su proyecto quitando el sample del nombre del archivo e indicarle al repositorio que lo va a ignorar en los push, esto para que la configuración local no sobre-escriba el archivo de configuración en producción

Comment: hola disculpa la demora en responder , lo que quiero hacer es algo igual que esta pregunta lo que no se como hacerlo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/174142/seleccionar-bases-de-datos-django